# MongoDB - FindById is not working and giving null

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring Boot(V2.2.2.RELEASE) + Spring Data Mongo Example. In this example, I've records like below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cb825e566135255e0bf38a4"),
    "firstName" : "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
}
```

My Repository

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, ObjectId>{
    Employee findById(String id);
}
```

Code

```
Employee findById = employeeRepository.findById("5cb825e566135255e0bf38a4");
System.out.println(findById);
```

Even below code not working

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("id").is(new ObjectId("5cb825e566135255e0bf38a4")));
List<Employee> find = mongoTemplate.find(query, Employee.class);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems there might be two issues

1. ObjectId should be used

```
employeeRepository.findById(new ObjectId("5cb825e566135255e0bf38a4"))
```

2. ID field goes with underscore

```
new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(new ObjectId("5cb825e566135255e0bf38a4")))
```

I'm not a Java guy, so might miss smth, but at least give it a try :)

Comment: This is still not working .. Please suggest what's wrong here

Comment: I found the mistake where `@Id private String id` was marked as `@Field`, hence creating an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Using the input document with `_id: ObjectId("5cb825e566135255e0bf38a4")` you can use either of the approaches. Assuming there is the document in the `employee` collection you can query by the `_id`'s string value.

```
public class Employee {
     @Id
     private String id;
     private String name;

    // constructors (with and with arguments)
    // get methods
    // override toString()
}

// Spring-data app using MongoTemplate
MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "test");
Query query = new Query(where("id").is("5cb825e566135255e0bf38a4"));
Employee emp = mongoOps.findOne(query, Employee.class);
```

*-or-*

> [MongoRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository.html)
>   interface extends CrudRepository and exposes the capabilities of the
>   underlying persistence technology in addition to the generic
>   persistence technology-agnostic interfaces such as CrudRepository.

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends MongoRepository<Employee, String> {
    @Query("{ 'id' : ?0 }")
    Optional<Employee> findById(String id);
}

// Spring-data app using the Repository
Optional<Employee> empOpt = employeeRepository.findById("5cb825e566135255e0bf38a4");

if (empOpt.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println(empOpt.get());
}
else {
   System.out.println("Employee not found!");
}
```

Comment: Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60931829/spring-data-mongo-findbyid-doesnt-works-for-long-id ?

Answer (score 1):

If you facing this problem,
Just add "_id:String" in your Mongodb schema.
Just look code below...

```
const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id:String,
    name: String,
    author: String,
    tags: Array,
    isPublished: Boolean,
    price: Number,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

const Course = mongoose.model('Course', courseSchema);

async function updateCourse(id) {
    const course = await Course.findById(id);
    if (!course) {
        console.log('Course does not exist with the given ID');
        return;
    }
    course.isPublished = true;
    course.author = 'Another Author';

    const result = await course.save();
    console.log(result);
}

updateCourse('5a68fdd7bee8ea64649c2777');
```

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the issue. Interestingly things are working fine with version 2.1.7RELEASE

`<documentRepository>.findById(<StringID>)` treats as String Id in 2.2.2RELEASE
while 2.1.7RELEASE transforms it to ObjectId and hence the find query works.