# Spring Boot findById not working for MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm trying to do a simple get query on springboot using mongodb as database engine

I have tried with several stuff(sending the data as ObjectId and even changing the repository)

```
public ResponseEntity<Track> get(String trackId) {
    Track find = mongoTemplate.findById(new ObjectId(trackId), Track.class);

    Optional<Track> track = tracksRepository.findById(trackId);

    if (track.isPresent()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(track.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

}
```

with mongo config

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "data.store.repositories")
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    private final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getSimpleName());

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {

        return MongoClients.create(MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyToClusterSettings(builder -> builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress(host, port))))
            .build());
    }

    private MongoCredential mongoCredentials() {
        return MongoCredential.createCredential(username, database, password.toCharArray());
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoClient(), getDatabaseName());
        mongoTemplate.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred());
        return mongoTemplate;
    }

    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return database;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean autoIndexCreation() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

EDIT: Adding class for context

```
@Document("track")
public class Track {
    @Id
    @Field(ATTR_ID)
    @JsonProperty(ATTR_ID)
    public String id;
    public static final String ATTR_ID = "id";
}
```

and getting always null, with existing keys on my database. could you help me find the issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: StackOverflow avoids me pasting more data. I'm using gradle
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.6.2")

Comment: to be more precise I tried all of these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60023943/mongodb-findbyid-is-not-working-and-giving-null

Comment: can you post the `Track` class also?

Comment: I also tried adding @MongoId to it (Sorry for adding it to comments. SO won't let me add it to the post)

Comment: You have two `findById` methods - one on the tracksRepository and the other on mongoTemplate. Which one is not working

Comment: @prasad_ none, both return always null

Comment: You can look at this SO post for some ideas: [How to initialize MongoClient once in Spring Boot and use its methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61663741/how-to-initialize-mongoclient-once-in-spring-boot-and-use-its-methods/61677205#61677205).

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with similar configuration class and found the following worked fine creating/accessing data using `MongoTemplate`.

The POJO class:

```
public class Test {
    
    @MongoId(FieldType.OBJECT_ID)
    private String id;
    private String name;
    
    public Test() {
    }
    public Test(String s) {
        super();
        this.name = s;
    }
    
    // get, set methods
    
    public String toString( ) {
        return id + " - " + name;
    }
}
```

From Spring's `CommandLineRunner.run()`:

```
    // Insert a document into the database
    Test t1 = new Test("alpha");
    t1 = mt.insert(t1);
    System.out.println(t1); // 61e7de9f5aadc2077d9f4a58 - alpha

    // Query from the database using the _id
    ObjectId id = new ObjectId("61e7de9f5aadc2077d9f4a58");
    Test t2 = mt.findById(id, Test.class);
    System.out.println(t2);
```

Note that you need to do this from the class where you are running the code:

```
@Autowired private MongoTemplate mt;
```

You can use the `@MongoId` or `@Id` annotations in our POJO class to represent MongoDB `_id` field. The type of the field can be a `String` or `ObjectId`. It depends upon how you define.

See this from Spring Data MongoDB documentation on *How the _id Field is Handled in the Mapping Layer using:*

- [@MongoId](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.id-handling)
- [@Id](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.conventions.id-field)

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to add to MongoId annotation field type object id

```
@MongoId(FieldType.OBJECT_ID)
private String id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing here just to refer to the solution that helped me.
Had more or less the same problem (collection with data) but somehow `Optional<T> findById(ID id)` from `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository` failed to find it.

Problem was that my Mongo init scripts imported IDs as strings:

```
{
  "_id" : "5a78a1d1ba09644244839536",
// rest of document
}
```

Resulted in exactly the same representation inside of DB which couldn't been picked up by `Optional<T> findById(ID id)`
Should be:

```
{
  "_id" : {"$oid":"5a78a1d1ba09644244839536"},
// rest of the document
}
```

Which results in following representation after import:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a78a1d1ba09644244839536"),
//...
}
```

Kind of obvious for me now but I've spent couple of days almost going crazy.

Following threads helped me:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60024234/13981676
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33507927/13981676

UPD: Went through docs a bit here's the answer: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.id-handling

Take special care if you have data that "*stored in MongoDB that did not run through the Spring Data mapping layer*". For example case of some init-scripts.