# Java Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, nosql, azure-cosmosdb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring data mongo with azure cosmos. My structure looks like below.
I have an Id field in my collection that is not annotated with @Id. I see both _id and id are in the DB but When I retrieve id field comes with the value is in _id.

```
@Document(collection = "mycollection")
class MyObject{
  private String id;
  ...
}

public interface MyRepository extends MongoRepository<MyObject, Void> {

}
```

Comment: You could try the @Field annotation on the id field. @Field("id")

Comment: What fields do you want in your database and what do you want to do with them? The `_id` field is a mandatory in the database for each document. You can provide a value to it or the driver/database will create one. You can use the annotations `@Id` or `@MongoId` to work with `_id` field. Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70762027/spring-boot-findbyid-not-working-for-mongodb/70768844#70768844

Comment: I want to have both of them(_id and id) in DB. I do not want to annotate any fields with `@Id` . Therefore mongo will create _id for each document But I also want to have `Id` field (Note: I did not annotate none of them with @Id)

Comment: Forgot to mention that I will assign value to Id field and use it like any other field. Not necessarily as id as pk field

Answer (score 0):

Used `@Field("id")` to tell spring data threat this field as is not as _id/pk field for mongo